# Mongodump Error : positional arguments not allowed: [abc]

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

The below comment throwing this error for mongodump

```
mongodump --host xx.xxx.xx.xxx -db abc --out home/dataBaseBackup/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed an -. The correct one is given below:

```
mongodump --host xx.xxx.xx.xxx --db abc --out home/dataBaseBackup/
```